The x-axis, y-axis, and title overlap the graph area
from openpyxl import *
from openpyxl.chart import *

wb = load_workbook("videogamesales.xlsx")
ws = wb["Breakdown of Sales by Year"]


chart = LineChart()

chart.title = "Total Sales"
chart.x_axis.title = "Year"
chart.y_axis.title = "Breakdown of Sales by Year"

value = Reference(ws, min_col=2, max_col=5, min_row=1, max_row=40)
cats = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_row=40)

chart.x_axis.delete = False
chart.y_axis.delete = False

chart.add_data(data=value, titles_from_data=True)
chart.set_categories(cats)

chart.style = 10
chart.width = 20
chart.height = 10
chart.legend.overlay = False

ws.add_chart(chart, "H2")

wb.save("videogamesales.xlsx")

The tutorial taught me I can make a clear graph without special attribute changing.
But it didn't work.
I solved the problem the legend overlap the graph area using 'chart.legend.overlay = False'
But I can't find the method for x_axis, y_axis and title.
Please help me.
graph image
I want a clear graph
graph image I want to have

What version of openpyxl did you use? If the latest try it with version 3.1.2

Add the parameter for the x_axis tick label position:
chart.x_axis.tickLblPos = "low"

It can be done for y_axis as
chart.y_axis.tickLblPos = "low"

Here is the complete documentation.

It works but it isn't clear still. I think my excel program is a problem. Because many example and tutorial say no need to change attribute when making a graph.
